# Get data from Pendo via Python api call

Tags: python

There are some reports created in Pendo (Like adobe ) . I want to pull this report via python api call .
I have written code which is partially incorrect .Please let me know what I'm doing wrong?
The output should be in form of table which contains 4 columns and their records.
This code is only returning - {'overall': {}, 'fields': {'pipeline': 'Required'}}
Which is strange.

```
pendo_key='123fgh21-ab89-ab23-21ad-bvh3r11r2sv5.ca'

import matplotlib.pyplot as pt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import requests
import os
import json

import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO
pd.set_option('display.max_colwidth',0)

url= "https://app.pendo.io/api/v1/aggregation"
headers = {
'X-Pendo-Integration-Key':pendo_key,
'Content-Type':'application/json'}


payload1= json.dumps({
  "response": {
    "location": "request",
    "mimeType": "application/json"
  },
  "requests": [
    {
      "name": "SalesEventAggregation",
      "pipeline": [
        {
          "source": {
            "salesEvents": {
              "blacklist": "apply",
              "salesTypeId": "dg_5w_fgtdergJ67vFdfR8kWsxi"
            },
            "timeSeries": {
              "period": "dayRange",
              "first": "now()",
              "count": 1
            }
          }
        }],
      "requestId": "saleseventAggregation-rId-etr1231-561s-6d6c-7d12-351f1d21gww2"
    }
  ]
}) 

response = requests.request("POST",url,headers=headers, data= payload1)
print("Status code:", response.status_code)
response_dict = json.loads(response.text)
response_dict




  Status code: 422
    
    Output:
    {'overall': {}, 'fields': {'pipeline': 'Required'}}

Expected:
There are 4 columns in form of table which is not showing up and their relevant records is not showing up.
```

Answer (score 1):

The "request" object is not an array, and the "key" should be named as "request"(singular) not as "requests"(plural).

Try

```
  payload1= json.dumps(
  {
  "response": {
    "location": "request",
    "mimeType": "application/json"
  },
  "request": 
    {
      "name": "SalesEventAggregation",
      "pipeline": [
        {
          "source": {
            "salesEvents": {
              "blacklist": "apply",
              "salesTypeId": "dg_5w_fgtdergJ67vFdfR8kWsxi"
            },
            "timeSeries": {
              "period": "dayRange",
              "first": "now()",
              "count": 1
            }
          }
        }],
      "requestId": "saleseventAggregation-rId-etr1231-561s-6d6c-7d12-351f1d21gww2"
    }
  
})
```